# Does python compiled file (pyc) needs the imported libraries on the system even though it is compile to bytecode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyc

When the `.py` file compiled the system has the necessary pip installs but i want to compile it and copy the `.pyc` into another server which has no pip installs. Or is there any alternative for this purpose?

Comment: I believe a ```.pyc``` file only compiles that file, not the imports. You probably want to look into an approach to convert python to exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying a Python application is unfortunately not trivial. Packages may have dependencies as DLLs or other files beyond .pyc and packages do not publish exactly what should be done to deploy the application.

You should check a packager (e.g. [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/index.html)) that is able to create a stand-alone executable from your source python program. It comes already with knowledge about how to deploy commonly used packages.

If you've custom or even just not very popular packages as dependencies then may be you'll have to specify exactly what files should be included in the distributed executable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it! I'd like to do something similar to jupyter notebooks/Google colab. I wonder how they implement it to achieve this.